# i'm serching a php code of the "stable marriage"

Tags: php

I searching for a php code of the "stable marriage problem" for a project that I'm writing...

I once wrote the code in java but now I need it for a php project.

I got the extension from GitHub but I don't really know what to do with it. I don't know if its a php file or something else.

thank you!

Comment: You got the extension but you "don't know if it's a php file?" Have you looked at it?

Comment: https://github.com/cutsea110/stable-marriage

Comment: this is the file... its have all kind of files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you provided in the comments does not contain a PHP file/library. It appears to be a Haskell library. This should point you in the right direction: https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2013/04/stable-marriage-problem-in-php/

Comment: thank you! it looks good... it's saying its code for Python...it will work on every php writing platform?

Comment: @אופירשטרן '...port the Python...' It was python; the code in the article is php.